# ARM binary size

Tags: c++, binary, arm, stm32, bin

I'm programming MCUs like STM32F4** and STM32F0**, using ARM GCC noneabi compiler , c/c++ and found interesting pattern.

> If I build some *.bin file, it's size is always divisible by 4.

I think it might be because MCU is 32bit (=4 byte). So bin_size%4==0. I have tried some "hacks"; for example enlarge some byte array by 1, but binary size is always the same. When I enlarge array more, binary size is bigger, but again divisible by 4.

> Can I consider this effect as axiom?

Or is there some situation when this doesn't work? For example, is it possible somehow switch 32bit STM32 MCU to 16bit mode? Or is possible to create non-divisible binary by 4 with another compiler?

Comment: Why on earth would you want the size of the binary not to be a multiple of 4 ???

Comment: What's your goal here? The compiler is probably padding your structures to ensure clean memory access. If you're going out of your way to break this, I don't know what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: open the file, add a byte to the end, close it, you can have an odd length file then see how many of the tools break when you try to use it...

Answer (score 6):

**It's possible to create binaries of arbitrary size**, the 4 byte alignment is just a matter of convenience. Everyone does it this way, and everyone expects it.

The alignment is enforced in the linker script file. If you look in the `*.ld` file of your project, you'll find that there are a lot of

```
. = ALIGN(4);
```

statements. They instruct the linker to advance the current output address to a value that's divisible by 4.

So I've created an empty project, and deleted most of the `ALIGN` lines from the linker script:

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
__stack = 0x20014000;
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
RAM   (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 80K
}
SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  .text :
  {
    *(.text)
    *(.text*)
  } >FLASH
  .rodata :
  {
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata*)
  } >FLASH
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
  .data : 
  {
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    _edata = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  .bss :
  {
    _sbss = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    _ebss = .;
  } >RAM
}
```

a minimal program:

```
void Reset_Handler(void) {
    while(1)
        ;
}
```

compiled and linked it with `-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib`, to leave out all the standard library stuff. The result is

```
arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "unaligned.elf"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    320       0       0     320     140 unaligned.elf
```

evenly divisible by four. Then I've added a char variable, and did something with it:

```
volatile char c = 0x42;
void Reset_Handler(void) {
    while(1)
        c+=1;
}
```

which resulted in

```
Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size
arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "unaligned.elf"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    336       1       0     337     151 unaligned.elf
Finished building: unaligned.siz
```

**The instructions are aligned to 16 bits.**

Cortex-M based MCUs like the STM32 series use the Thumb2 instruction set, which is a mix of 16 and 32 bit instructions. It turns out that our first program just happened to have a length divisible by four. I've added a single `nop` instruction

```
void Reset_Handler(void) {
    asm("nop");
    while(1)
        ;
}
```

and the size grew by two bytes, compared to the original:

```
Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size
arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "unaligned.elf"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    322       0       0     322     142 unaligned.elf
Finished building: unaligned.siz
```

Comment: Great, your answer totally covered all questions I need to know!
I have opened my *.ld file and there is . = ALIGN(4) in every section. So that might be reason why my binaries sizes were always divisible by 4.

I was asking because I have my own bootloader which has ability to flash new binary file to MCU and I considered "divisible by 4" rule as one of the rules which must new binary pass, together with CRC check and so on. Now I know it's not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

"For example, is it possible somehow switch 32bit STM32 MCU to 16bit mode"

There *is* a 16 bits mode, but you may not understand exactly what that implies. To google it, you'd search for "ARM Thumb". That might very well result in *bin files which are a multiple of 2 bytes.

However, "32 bits mode" and "16 bits mode" usually refer to pointer or register sizes, not instruction sizes E.g. the AMD x64 instruction set may be referred to as "64 bits mode", even though its instructions are variable-length. Some x64 instructions are just one byte.